# How to activate a tab in JavaScript with an anchor

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tabs, anchor

I want to activate, in a same page, a tab (all tabs have an `ID` as `#tab1`, `#tab2`, `#tab3`...) when I click on a `#url`...
For example, activate the `#tab3` when I click on a link like `href="#tab3"`.

I think it's very easy but not for me..
Here is the HTML code :

```
<div class="tabs p3">
    <ul class="nav">
        <li class="selected"><a href="#tab1">popular</a></li>
        <li class=""><a href="#tab2">featured</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tab1" class="tab-content" style="display: block; ">
        <div class="inner">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor elit.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="tab2" class="tab-content" style="display: none; ">
        <div class="inner">
            <p>Phasellus non mi vel turpis gravida rhoncus eget lacinia tellus.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

So, if I click on the `<a href="#tab2">`, the `#tab2` is activate. No problem. But if I insert a link as `<a href="#tab2">` anywhere on my page, this link don't activate this tab...
Probably I need to create an anchor like `<a name="tab2">` on my `#tab2`? But it doesn't works.

Here is the javascript code I use for the tabs :

```
$(function(){
    tabs.init();
}); 
tabs = {
    init : function(){
        $('.tabs').each(function(){
            $(this).find('.tab-content').hide();
            $($(this).find('ul.nav .selected a').attr('href')).fadeIn(300);
            $(this).find('ul.nav a').click(function(){
                $(this).parents('.tabs').find('.tab-content').hide();
                $($(this).attr('href')).fadeIn(300);
                $(this).parent().addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');
                return false;
            });
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Would you show the related markup as well. It's difficult to write jQuery code without seeing the html structure.

Comment: [http://jsfiddle.net/didierg/bVDra/](http://jsfiddle.net/didierg/bVDra/) works for me... what is the problem ?

Comment: Thnak Didier..i test..but it'dont work...perhaps a problemen with the fonction (e) line 20..?

Comment: What is the error you get ? I have updated my answer with the full code, your problem is maybe because of the `$tab` variable. Also check the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/didierg/bVDra/) I've put in place.

Comment: Thank you Didier. But it don't work....no append....and the debugger show me the same probleme line 20....

Comment: But **what** problem ? **What** is the error you get ?

Comment: no append...and the call stack of chrome inspector show me a probleme inside the line 20 after fonction(e)...

Comment: If you don't show me the error message you get I cannot help you. I don't get any errors in the jsfiddle and it works so... I'm not a magician.

Comment: Thnaks didier...I will be use your jquery tools tab as you preconise..sorry for this spend time ! Thank much !

Answer (score 0):

I understand a bit better what you're after now.

Well, if you want links **inside** the tab-content to point to other tabs **of the same group** you can do the following:

```
// find all <a> with href start with a '#' in tab-content
$tab.find('.tab-content a[href^="#"]').click(function(e) {

    $tab.find('.nav a[href="' + $(this).attr('href') + '"]').trigger('click');

    return false;
});
```

Here is the full code, a bit optimized (check the comments):

```
    $('.tabs').each(function() {

        // save $(this) (the .tabs container) for re-use
        var $tab = $(this);

        $tab.find('.tab-content').hide();
        $($tab.find('.nav .selected a').attr('href')).fadeIn(300);

        $tab.find('.nav a').click(function(){

            // save $(this) (the clicked link) for re-use
            var $a = $(this);

            $a.parents('.tabs').find('.tab-content').hide();
            $($a.attr('href')).fadeIn(300);
            $a.parent().addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');

            return false;

        });

        // find all <a> with href start with a '#' in tab-content
        $tab.find('.tab-content a[href^="#"]').click(function(e) {

            $tab.find('.nav a[href="' + $(this).attr('href') + '"]').trigger('click');

            return false;
        });
    });
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/didierg/bVDra/)**

If you want a link **anywhere** on the page to open a specific tab of any tab group, this is a way more complex issue.

Why don't you turn to already existing, full-featured plugin to have a tab system like:

- [jQuery UI Tabs](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/)
- [jQuery Tools Tabs](http://flowplayer.org/tools/tabs/index.html)